# Linking with both Pardsio 5.0.0 and Intel MKL

Tags: c++, cmake, eigen, intel-mkl, pardiso

I would like to compile my code with MKL support (I use Eigen), as well as the new [Pardiso solver](http://www.pardiso-project.org/). The problem is that MKL ships with an (old) version of Pardiso, whose interface functions are incompatible with Pardiso 5.0.0.

More precisely, I get the following errors on compilation:

```
error: conflicting declaration of C function ‘void pardisoinit(void*, int*, int*, int*, double*, int*)’
...
error: conflicting declaration of C function ‘void pardiso(void*, int*, int*, int*, int*, int*, double*, int*, int*, int*, int*, int*, int*, double*, double*, int*, double*)’
...
```

Is it possible to compile and link both in the same application? It is unfortunate having to choose, as my code is overall faster with MKL, but Pardiso 5.0.0 gets me the faster linear solver among the crowd.

Comment: Have you solved this?